# mysql group by / select distinct

Tags: mysql, opencart, opencart-3

I have a column in my database named baseModel that I would like to use as a group by in the following SQl.
some of the items have the same baseModel value but I'm not really sure how to modify the query to select only one item per value.

```
        SELECT
            DISTINCT(p.baseModel), p.product_id,
            (
                SELECT AVG(rating) total
                FROM `oc_review` r1
                WHERE
                    r1.product_id = p.product_id
                    AND r1.status = '1'
                GROUP BY r1.product_id
            ) rating,
            (
                SELECT price
                FROM `oc_product_discount` pd2
                WHERE
                    pd2.product_id = p.product_id
                    AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1'
                    AND pd2.quantity = '1'
                    AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW())
                    AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW()))
                ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1
            ) discount,
            (
                SELECT price
                FROM `oc_product_special` ps
                WHERE
                    ps.product_id = p.product_id
                    AND ps.customer_group_id = '1'
                    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW())
                    AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW()))
                ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1
            ) special,
            p.viewed
     FROM `oc_product` p LEFT JOIN `oc_product_to_category` p2c ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) LEFT JOIN `oc_category_path` cp ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)
        LEFT JOIN `oc_product_description` pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
        LEFT JOIN `oc_product_to_store` p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
        WHERE
            p.status = '1'
            AND p.date_available <= NOW()
            AND p2s.store_id = '0'
            AND pd.language_id = '2'
     AND cp.path_id = '291' GROUP BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.sort_order ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC LIMIT 0, 36
```

Comment: group by needs to have some aggregate method, like count, sum etc

Comment: DISTINCT is **NOT** a function. It is applied to whole row, not to separate column in it. You use `GROUP BY p.product_id`, and this column is present in the output - so each row is unique and DISTINCT is excess in the query.

Comment: if i do a group by p.baseModel I'm getting the following error Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column